# Receiving JSON from Looker - in PHP

Tags: php, json, webhooks, looker

I'm creating a web hook to receive a JSON POST from the tool Looker (http://looker.com).
My problem is that I receive no data although I know for sure that Looker sends data (has been tested with https://requestb.in). The data is sent as an attached JSON payload.

My PHP code is this:

```
<?php
setlocale(LC_ALL,'da_DK.UTF8');
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
require("functions.php"); //a file containing some functions
$json = file_get_contents('php://input'); 
jsonLog($json); //a small function that writes the content to a file (for testing)
?>
```

When testing my web hook through postman, everything works fine.

Can anyone spot an error in my PHP code? Is it a header thing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what's your php/apache logs says?

Comment: The access log says this: 
52.16.163.151 - - [11/Dec/2017:13:58:18 +0100] "POST /tgtg/json-log.php HTTP/1.1" 200 3069 "-" "LookerOutgoingWebhook/5.2.19"

Comment: What is an *"attached JSON payload"*? Can you share some screenshots from requestb.in ?